# spring-data-jpa, to clone ManyToMany mapping table

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have below JPA Entity 
(using spring-data-jpa 1.9.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.3.11.Final)

```
@Getter @Setter @Entity @Table(name = "product")
class Product {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "product_attachment",
    joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    }
  )
  private List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

and I need to clone `product` and `product_attachment` columns.
(not `attachment`, so it is master table)

```
private Product _clone(Product src) {

  Product dst = new Product();
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, dst, "id", "attachments");

  dst.setAttachments(src.getAttachments());

  return productRepository.save(dst);
}
```

But I got below Exception.

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: Product.attachments`

My workaround of this problem is getting same entity again. code is below.

```
private Product _clone(Product src) {

  Product dst = new Product();
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, dst, "id", "attachments");

  dst.setAttachments(
    attachmentRepository.findAll(
      src.getAttachments().stream()
        .map(Attachment::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
  );

  return productRepository.save(dst);
}
```

But It seems to redundant, Anyone know better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not clone the collection `attachments` itselfe, instead you have to copy its content. (I think the reasons is that Hibernate use some hacks to detect changed on the collection content).

```
 dst.attachments = new ArrayList(src.attachments);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your copied list is referencing the Attachments from the source Product (shallow).

You should copy Attachment entries using the same method as you copy Product manually:

```
Product dst = new Product();
BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, dst, "id", "attachments");
dst.setAttachments(new ArrayList<Attachment>(src.getAttachments().size()));
for(Attachment a : src.getAttachments()){
    Attachment dstA = new Attachment();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(a, dstA, {Your properties});
    a.getAttachments().add(dstA);
}
```

Or you could use a helper class such as Apache Commons [SerializationUtils.clone()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone(T)) method to perform a deep copy of your source Product.